# Subir página desarrollada en CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, dominio

estoy intentando subir una pagina web desarrollada con el Framework CodeIgniter pero no me queda.

Estos son los directorios con los que cuenta el hosting cuando lo compre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después lo que hice fue agregar mi proyecto de CodeIgniter al directorio de public_html y quedo de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente cambie la base_url del proyecto. Algo asi quedo la base_url:

$config['base_url'] = 'http://dominio.com.mx/VDCServicios/';

Pero no se esta mostrando, entonces cree un solo archivo llamado index.php con un echo que dijera Hola y si lo muestra, ¿Hay algo que me esté faltando?

Comment: ¿Porque razón no califican sus preguntas y respectivas respuestas? o si ya tienes la solucion ponerla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También asegúrate en tu archivo index.php (de Codeigniter) definir el ENVIRONMENT por development, si de pronto no te funciona aún, recuerda que en el servidor se distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas a los controladores y modelos -> cada directorio (controlador y modelo) pon la primera letra en mayúscula.

Comment: Muchas gracias , eran las mayusculas al inicio.